# Reload single file in every window

Tags: buffers, files, kill-buffer, revert-buffer

I have this function that reload a file but it don't work when I have same buffer opened in 2 different windows:

```
(defun reload ()
  "Reload a file

it will kill buffer, open file again and jump to position where cursor when called"
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename buffer-file-name)
        (postion (point)))
    (if filename
        (progn
          (kill-buffer)
          (find-file filename)
          (goto-char postion)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear to me just what you are looking for.  I get the impression that you just want to revert the buffer and then restore the position from before reverting.  If so, that's this:

```el
(defun revert+restore-pos ()
  "Revert buffer, then restore previous position."
  (interactive)
  (let ((pt  (point)))
    (revert-buffer t t)
    (goto-char pt)))
```

That also restores the `window-point` to where it was in each window showing the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun reload ()
  "Reload a file

it will kill buffer, open file again and jump to position where cursor when called"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((filename buffer-file-name)
        (name (buffer-name))
        (postion (point))
        (windows (remove-if-not (lambda (window)
                                  (equal name (buffer-name (window-buffer window))))
                                (get-buffer-window-list))))
    (if filename
        (progn
          (kill-buffer)
          (find-file filename)
          (goto-char postion)
          (let ((buffer (get-buffer (buffer-name))))
            (save-current-buffer
              (dolist (window windows)
                (set-window-buffer window buffer)
                (set-buffer (window-buffer window)))))))))
```